# org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'siteids_sm

Tags: solr

I have made lucene to solr index configuration changes which is working fine where i don't have query on collection but there is one issue I am struggling  that my query on collection is giving parse error
when i check query in search logs, query has some part like below

```
siteids_sm:(*{B8F5FEB9-F9D2-41AA-9084-96A46733FA45}*)
```

I am getting error

> org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse
>   'siteids_sm:(*{B8F5FEB9-F9D2-41AA-9084-66A46733FA45}*)': Encountered
>   \" \"}\" \"} \"\" at line 1, column 50.\r\nWas expecting:\r\n
>   \"TO\" ...\r\n    "

My index has collection data in this format

```
siteids_sm":["{B8F5FEB9-F9D2-41AA-9084-96A46733FA45}",
          "{64FC325A-5BBD-4B02-BCD0-980386643E21}"]
```

Can someone please suggest what could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: It seems syntax error in your query. generally, a field with `_sm` indicates string collection or guid collection in Solr. Could you please make sure that you have guid in the field nor ID? also if `siteids` is a computed field could you please share the code?

Comment: SOLR is generating this query in back-end which can not be modified. Its not just siteids, every collection in the query has same syntax which doesn't work if I try in separate solr query interface. All computed fields with type collection were working fine with lucene but this started happening after changing this to SOLR although I have updated all configuration for SOLR but looks something is not right.

Comment: Could you show full query from search logs, please? Error is saying "Was expecting 
TO". My assumption is that you have "[" character somewhere in query, that is why Solr expect "TO somevalue]", but don't get it.

Comment: ((keywords_sm:(army1~0.7) OR _name:(army1)) AND (((_language:(en) AND (-_name:("\*__Standard Values")  *:*)) 
AND ((((siteids_sm:(*{B8F5FEB9-F9D2-41AA-9084-66A46733FA45}*))^0 
OR (siteids_sm:(*NULL*))^0 
OR (siteids_sm:(*{8215C3BE-434F-49A2-802A-EB021EBD6782}*))^0) 
AND ((all_templates_sm:(*{F56EB247-16C8-4046-849E-ABB42B907D4D}*))^0 
OR (all_templates_sm:(*{F56EB247-16C8-4046-849E-ABB42B907D4D}*))^0)) 
AND ((_eventisinthepast_b:(*0*))^0 OR (_eventisinthepast_b:(*NULLVALUE*))^0))) 
AND (excludefromsearch_b:(0))^0))&start=0&rows=21&fl=*,score&fq=_indexname:(x_content_index)&wt=xml

Comment: Could you provide your code for query and indexing? Guid search for `_sm` field should looks like `siteids_sm:(B8F5FEB9F9D241AA908466A46733FA45)`, and indexing value should also looks like `siteids_sm":["B8F5FEB9F9D241AA908496A46733FA45",  "64FC325A5BBD4B02BCD0980386643E21"]` without '}' character.

Comment: Is siteids a custom field/computed field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
siteids_sm:"*{B8F5FEB9-F9D2-41AA-9084-96A46733FA45}*"
```

for collection feild.

Comment: SOLR is generating this query in back-end which can not be modified. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Can u pls share the solr query you are using